# How to reduce clicking in an audio signal with seek jumps?

Tags: audio, delay

I'm working on a vst plugin where a delay is used, the seek position of the delay sometimes changes gradually sometimes abruptly, when sudden changes occur sometimes a clicking sound is produced.

Some VSTs like GrossBeat (similar plugin) have an option to reduce clicking, what methods can they be using to reduce clicking sound when changing the playback position? If the solution is a cross-fade, any tips on how to implement it?

Comment: You could try to perform some kind of interpolation between the previous and the new sample. This in essence is kind of the same thing as the cross-fade suggested by SakSath in their answer below, but only for two samples (or possibly more past samples if you intend to try use anything other than linear interpolation).

Answer (score 4):

Clicking noise on seek is a result of discontinuity in the audio signal. One way of reducing this noise is applying a fade-in effect for few frames post seek.

Comment: You might want a slight fade out pre seek as well

Comment: Yes, Fade out at the pre seek is good to have as well! @Jdip

Comment: Thanks, I'm struggling with the implementation but sounds like the way to go, that or interpolation as Zaellix suggests.

Comment: Managed to implement a cross-fade and the clicking is gone, thanks again.

Comment: Great! Don’t forget to mark the answer as “accepted” ;)